# Django simple_jwt auth worked with blank token

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

My project is running jwt authorization based on the simple_jwt library. Despite the fact that I do not pass the Authorization: Bearer token header, the request passes and returns 201, but if I pass the wrong token, everything works as it should and 401 is returned.
My settings:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    ],
}


SIMPLE_JWT = {
    'ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(minutes=5),
    'REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=1),
    'ROTATE_REFRESH_TOKENS': False,
    'BLACKLIST_AFTER_ROTATION': False,
    'UPDATE_LAST_LOGIN': False,

    'ALGORITHM': 'HS256',
    'SIGNING_KEY': SECRET_KEY,
    'VERIFYING_KEY': None,
    'AUDIENCE': None,
    'ISSUER': None,
    'JWK_URL': None,
    'LEEWAY': 0,

    'AUTH_HEADER_TYPES': ('Bearer',),
    'AUTH_HEADER_NAME': 'HTTP_AUTHORIZATION',
    'USER_ID_FIELD': 'phone_number',
    'USER_ID_CLAIM': 'client_phone_number',
    'USER_AUTHENTICATION_RULE': 'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.default_user_authentication_rule',

    'AUTH_TOKEN_CLASSES': ('rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens.AccessToken',),
    'TOKEN_TYPE_CLAIM': 'token_type',

    'JTI_CLAIM': 'jti',

    'SLIDING_TOKEN_REFRESH_EXP_CLAIM': 'refresh_exp',
    'SLIDING_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(minutes=5),
    'SLIDING_TOKEN_REFRESH_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=1),
}
```

MyView:

```
class SetPin(generics.CreateAPIView):
    """Change or set pin code"""
    serializer_class = serializers.PinSerializer
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As I see from your settings, it seems that you have not specified model permission and by default, Django will use **AllowAny** permission.

The default permission policy may be set globally, using the **DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES** setting. For example.

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ]
}
```

If not specified, this setting defaults to allowing unrestricted access:

```
'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
   'rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny',
]
```